# Get executed dll file of dotnet process in C#

Tags: c#

I have a method which list active processes and for those which filename is dotnet.exe, I want to see the dll executed.

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
var process = processes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Module.FileName.Equals(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

How to check the dll used with dotnet command using `Process` in C#?

Comment: i think you need to call process.GetCommandLine() for each process to view the command line arguments that started the process in the first place.

Comment: `process.GetCommandLine()` does not exist

Comment: You are right I was looking at an extension method I wrote.. Did not realize it was my own extension method. You need to use WMI

Comment: Someone has wrongly closed your question.  I requested a moderator to reopen it.

Comment: Yes, this is clearly not a duplicate of the linked question